# How could i populate document after .save function with pre hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have pre hook to populate needed fields set up as `schema.pre(/^find/, fn)`. Now i'm trying to get same sort of system to work with `document.save()` function, sadly it doesn't work neither with `schema.pre('save')` nor with `schema.post('save')`

So, this would populate fields totally fine:

```js
let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: user._id}, {$set: {testFieldWithRef: someObjectId}}, {new: true});
console.log(user.testFieldWithRef) //would output populated field instead of objectId
```

That one wouldn't populate fields with mine `.pre` hooks

```js
let user = await User.findOne({_id: user._id})
user.testFieldWithRef = someObjectId
user.markModified('testFieldWithRef')
user = await user.save()
console.log(user.testFieldWithRef) //would output someObjectId
```

Answer (score 4):

So, that has worked. Sad that mongoose isn't that popular on stackoverflow

```js
schema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    await this.populate({
        path: 'testFieldWithRef'
    }).execPopulate();
    next()
})
```

Comment: Nice one bro 